# Always "bundle install" before "bundle exec"?

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, bundler

What is the best practice to ensure that dependencies are installed on a build node for any build of a gem?

`bundle exec` will fail if some of the dependencies are not already installed.

Should I do

```
bundle install
bundle exec rake
```

on every build?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

The `bin/setup` script that ships with rails uses `bundle check || bundle install` as a pre-cursor step. That might be a good place to start.

I use `bundle install --frozen` on our pipelines; frozen makes sure no changes to Gemfile.lock occur. We use a cache, so I don't even bother with the `bundle check` step.

If you can provide more details about your setup (docker? kubernetes? a hosted provider?) someone might be able to recommend a caching strategy for bundler, if it's the bundle install time that's creating the question.

Typically though, for CI pipelines we always run `bundle install --frozen` early in our build, even if we have a caching mechanism setup. I've noticed in certain situations the executables aren't linked automatically when restoring form cache so this makes sure everything works. It's not slow by any means; with caching the `bundle install --frozen` step takes only a second or 2.

Answer (score -2):

`Bundler` provides a consistent environment for Ruby projects by tracking and installing the exact gems and versions that are needed. `Bundler` ensures that the gems you need are present in development, staging, and production.

To start work on a project with all the required gems, run:
`bundle install`

`bundle exec` is a `Bundler` command to execute a script in the context of the current bundle (the one from your directory's Gemfile). 
For example to run migration command from the current gem set, run:

`bundle exec rake db:migrate` is the script where db is the namespace and migrate is the task name defined.

Hope it gives some insights.

Comment: Copy-pasted from [bundler.io](https://bundler.io) and does not even try to answer the question.